# Keypress and values

Tags: jquery

I created a table and fill it with random numbers . Now I want to find them, at the same time use the keypress. If a match is found , select a cell in a different color. How to convert a understandable value eventObject.which

```
 function keyPress()
    {
        $('#search').keypress(function (eventObject) {
            $('td').each(function(index, element)
            {
                $(element).val() = eventObject.which

            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: is it be `$(element).val(eventObject.which)`

Comment: I have a lot of numbers. I would like to, for example, to find 99 of my table. How to do it?

Comment: use `('td').on('click', function(){this.val() // will give you value});`

Comment: I do not want to use click only keypress

Answer (score 1):

Since your elments are `td`s, you'll need to use `html()` not `val()` to get or set their contents. see below:

```js
$('#search').keyup(function (e) {
       //var pressed = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
       var search = $(this).val();
      $('td').removeClass('found');
       $('td').each(function(index, element){
                if($(element).html() == search){
                  $(element).addClass('found');
                }

       });
});
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" value="" />
<br>
<br>
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>345</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Y are awesome ) Snx :)

Comment: OK. I do it ) SNx ^_^

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery `val()` method is a getter and setter method, you don't assign to it, you pass in parameters.

```
$(element).val(eventObject.which);
```

Comment: still does not work. What am I doing wrong
`function keyPress()
        {
            $('#search').keypress(function (eventObject) {
                $('td').val(eventObject.which)
            });
        }`

Comment: to set the contents of a `td` element you would need `$(element).html()`

Comment: He's right, `val` is for input elements, `html`/`text` is for normal elements.